# how to make htaccess Rewriterule for a file on root?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

I am using Yii framework, I have a file on the website root named test.php, I want to make a rule that redirects this link "staging.mysite.com/p/test" to this file. what I did:

```
RewriteRule ^p/test$ test.php [QSA,L]
```

But I got this error

> Internal Server Error
>   Application runtime path "/var/www/staging.mysite.com/protected/_ws/runtime" is not valid. Please make sure it is a directory writable by the Web server process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says your runtime folder is missing.

try create a runtime folder under /var/www/staging.mysite.com/protected/_ws/

and make the permission to be 775

Then try again?

Comment: Yeah your are right, I didn't notice that the test.php is trying to include the runtime...it should be just a static file, so the problem solved by removing the runtime implementation from this file, thanks.